# create view with union all using select not working

Tags: oracle, group-by, view, union-all

I have below query where i am getting error as `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` and also logically its not working.

Normally the logic should be for every `FUND_ISIN` check the value for `member_descr`. If for `FUND_ISIN` the `member_descr != 'O'` or `member_descr` is `null` then take all the rows from `IS_ID` table. For every `FUND_ISIN` if the `member_descr = 'O'` then do calculation for `member_ratio` fields value such as `100-sum(all the values for member_ratio where member_descr!='O')`.

For example in this case the expected output will be like below. We can see below for `FUND_ISIN` L000123 we check for `member_descr = 'O'` and then did calculation as `100-(8.5643 + 6.94816) = 84,48754` and for other rows where `member_descr!= 'O'` we just take those rows. In this way we have to do for every `fund_isin`.

Output expected:

```
FUND_ISIN  FUND_QUOTE_CRNY  MEMBER_DESCR  MEMBER_RATIO  ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE
L000123       USD               O           84,48754       Other total
L000123       USD               null        8.5643         Cash total
L000123       USD               null        6.94816        member
```

Below is fiddle which is currently throwing not a group by expression error:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f48a9a4f439869168775bb2c7283db6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating your query. There is no need for a `UNION ALL` or even a `GROUP BY` to achieve the desired output. You can use analytic functions to achieve your result.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT fund_isin,
       fund_quote_crny,
       member_descr,
       CASE member_descr
           WHEN 'O'
           THEN
                 100
               - SUM (CASE member_descr WHEN 'O' THEN 0 ELSE member_ratio END)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY fund_isin)
           ELSE
               member_ratio
       END    AS member_ratio,
       allocationassettype
  FROM is_id;
```

#### Result

```
   FUND_ISIN    FUND_QUOTE_CRNY    MEMBER_DESCR    MEMBER_RATIO    ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE
____________ __________________ _______________ _______________ ______________________
L000123      USD                O                      84.48754 Other total
L000123      USD                null                    6.94816 member
L000123      USD                null                     8.5643 Cash total
```